# Cocoa-Touch – UITableView setEditing will not show specific cells

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, edit

I've been struggling with this problem for a good 2 hours now and I can not get it to work.

I have a view controller with a table view on it with a list of items. When the user touches the EDIT button in the navigation bar the table view should enter "edit mode" and under the list of items **one** new cell should appear that should only be visible when it is in "edit mode".

So in my `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method I'm checking `if (tableView.isEditing)` to setup the cell. I've tried overriding `-setEditing:animated:` and doing `[tableView reloadData]` calls but I just can't get it to work.

This is what my `-setEditing:animated:` look like:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.groupDetailsTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

My `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];


    if (tableView.isEditing) {

            // Other tableview code has been omitted

            UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                                           reuseIdentifier:nil];

            // Set the background view of the cell to be transparent        
            UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.backgroundView = backView;

            UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [deleteButton setFrame:[cell.contentView frame]];
            [deleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width-20, 44)];
            [deleteButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [deleteButton setTitle:@"Delete Group" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [deleteButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
            [deleteButton.titleLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            [deleteButton.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
            [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteGroup) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:deleteButton];

            return cell;

        }
}
```

And I'm calling `[self setEditing:YES animated:YES];` from a method when the user touches the Edit button. I've also tried just calling `[super setEditing:YES animated:YES];` and `[self.groupDetailsTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW19

Apparently `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` doesn't get called automatically when calling `-setEditing:animated:`

So to have a new cell "appear" I set the alpha to 0.0 and then 1.0 after calling setEditing...